# path with text mouseleftbuttonup event don't fired

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have interactive path's sketch, it has text indicating the name of each path, when the path is clicked is filled with a solid brush, when another path is cliked that first filled path is unfilled and the new selected path is filled and go on
But of course when i click the text the Path's MouseLeftButtonUp Event isn't fire how can i solve that?

Comment: If it's a WPF control it should have a `IsHitTestVisible` property. Is that set to `true`?

Comment: Thank's that's the propertie i was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, ensure the `IsHitTestVisible` property is set to `true`.

See the [documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible(v=vs.110).aspx).